# Get file property

Tags: iphone

How to get file size of pdf,gif,doc etc using xcode.
suppose to i get pdf file form resorce folder so how can i get size of for this file.

is there any way?

Thanks you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to calculate the size of your resource file in run-time basically you can do the following (omitting error checks etc):

```
// Get path for resource file
NSString *resourcePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myPDFFile" ofType:@"pdf"];
// Get file attributes
NSDictionary* attributeDict = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:resourcePath error:nil];
// Get size attribute
NSNumber* fileSizeObj = [attributeDict objectForKey:NSFileSize];
long long fileSizeVal = [fileSizeObj lonLongValue];
```

Comment: thanks for your replay but i have one question can i get creation date of file?

Comment: See this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1140696/cant-get-filecreationdate, this key may be not supported in iPhoneOS